# VB6, ActiveX: Cannot create reference to OCX

Tags: vb6, user-controls, activex, circular-dependency

I have a little problem with the creation of a user control.

Though I have made a control I want to use in another control.

As soon as I want to add the reference (would like to use it as compiled OCX) in the Component's list, the message "Wechselseitiger Verweis zwischen Projekten nicht zulässig" which means something like "Circular referencing between projects is not allowed"

Strange is that the control I want to use does not have any type of reference to the first project.

I've checked this using dependency walker which is shipped as a tool with Visual Studio, but it says as well that there's no reference to the other control. I've opened the project-files using a text-editor to check for referenced OCX, I didn't find any.

To avoid some comments: change to .NET or any other language is not an option.

**Comment:** Why ever, adding the uncompiled .ctl-file seems to work. For now I can continue my work. But anyways I'm interested in a solution and the reason why it doesn't work with the current constellation.

**VOTE FOR CLOSE:** I've been looking at all the files, well and now I've just simply added all control-files to the project instead of creating OCX. I'll give it up. Thanks to all...

Comment: Post the text of both VBP files.

Comment: COM references (dependancies) will not be exposed by dependancy walker. Dependancy walker will show you import/exports of specific entry points used by one dll to directly call one another without the use of a COM layer or instancing objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible for VB6 to get quite confused when you add **references** to OCX files.  You should really be adding an OCX as a **component** instead of using Project References.

Comment: well I right-click on the empty space on Toolbox and click Components. In this window, i add the OCX... sorry if my description is a bit confusing.